# Mongodb; use of the index in queries with a multiple condition

Tags: regex, mongodb, indexing, multiple-conditions

I use MongoDB. I create a database(500 000 000 documents) and collection in it for testing reasons. All documents look like bellow:

```
{

        "_id" : ObjectId("50c1fbcda8cf8e11c43ea8ce"),
        "sql_id" : 8311,
        "text" : "WD7TYIM0H H3Q 3874 000 VFBF6H",
        "xml" : "<root> <tag_0>WD7TYIM0H</tag_0> <tag_1>H3Q</tag_1> <tag_2>3874</tag_2><tag_3>000</tag_3><tag_4>VFBF6H</tag_4></root>",
        "tags" : [
                "WD7TYIM0H",
                "H3Q",
                "3874",
                "000",
                "VFBF6H"
        ]
}
```

I create index by field "tags" and want to use multiple regexp condition that uses "tags" index. Is this possible?

I tried:

```
> db.items.find({ "$and" : [{ "tags" : /^AAA/ }, { "tags" : /^BBB/ }] })

> db.items.find({ "tags" : { "$all" : [/^AAA/, /^BBB/] } })
```

twice Mongo went down.

If I search by one condition result returns very fast.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you combine both queries into a single regex?

Comment: I want to retrieve all documents that contain the tag AAA and BBB simultaneously. So I can not use one regular expression, as /^AAA/ <=> /^AAA*/ [guids](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operators/#_S_regex) , and the query shows docs сontaining tags "AAA_1","AAA_2","AAA_3"...

Comment: The reason is that you have huge collection (and I am not sure about your machine specificiation), and when you use the regex, even if "tags" are indexed, it is not really going to use that because of the nature of the regex evaluation.  You can do an explain on the shell and see what is the Cursor look like.  When it is very huge to iterate, of course it is going to take a long time.

Comment: What is fast? monogo went down means crashed? What is the collection size? What is the index size? Do you have a LOT of Tags in one doc or just some? Please provide metrics : .explain()

Answer (score 0):

In my test it goes well. I'm using db version v1.6.5. Given the fact that I have only a few documents in DB, the problem may be a performance-related one.

Comment: MongoDB 1.6.5 is comparatively ancient (released Dec 8, 2010).  Definitely worth updating to the latest production release (currently 2.2.x) for improved performance and concurrency.